# What is the most efficient way to apply a theme to multiple PowerPoint presentations?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, themes

Say I need to change the copyright text in the slide master.

Now I want to apply the updated theme/slide master to a bunch of existing presentations.

What is the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: Do you have any programming experience, particularly with VBA?